# Regex to match symbol & - . '

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a Regex test in JavaScript that will test a string to contain any of these characters:

```
 a...z A..Z 0..9 and  & - . '
```

I have do this but not match:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9&.-]
```

***Complete Code:***

```
    <field-validator type="regex">
        <param name="expression">^[a-zA-Z0-9&.-]+$</param>
        <param name="caseSensitive">false</param>
        <message key="format.name" />
    </field-validator>
```

Comment: You mean it has to match the first regex, but not the second?

Comment: What does your string start with?

Comment: So you want to match `& - . '`: then why do you look for `a-zA-Z0-9`, and why don't you list the single quote? Seems trivial that you should remove those characters and add the quote, or I completely miss your point.

Comment: @trincot i want to match alphanumeric char and `&-.'`

Comment: OK, then why not write that in your question?

Comment: @trincot i have edit my post

Comment: escape hypen(-) with \ because it specifies range in [ ] square bracket

Comment: Try XML entity for `&`: `<param name="expression">^[a-zA-Z0-9&amp;.-]+$</param>`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your response is exact so of can include `'` character

Comment: A `'` can be added as `&apos;` - `<param name="expression">^[a-zA-Z0-9&amp;&apos;.-]+$</param>`. Does it work for you? Or try hex values: `<param name="expression">^[a-zA-Z0-9\x26\x27.-]+$</param>`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew with your expression numbers and `'` not work

Comment: Try also hex values: `<param name="expression">^[a-zA-Z0-9\x26\x27.-]+$</param>`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew 
it does not change anything

Comment: Last try to understand what you need - what if you remove `^` and `$`? `<param name="expression">[a-zA-Z0-9\x26\x27.-]</param>`? Or just in case a full string match is expected - `<param name="expression">.*[a-zA-Z0-9\x26\x27.-].*</param>`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122106/discussion-between-mercer-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the regex inside XML file, so best way is to use a CDATA block in order to use literal `&` and `'` symbols inside it. Either of the two will work:

```
<param name="regex"><![CDATA[[a-zA-Z0-9'&.-]]]></param>
```

or (if a full string match is required):

```
<param name="regex"><![CDATA[(?s).*[a-zA-Z0-9'&.-].*]]></param>
```

Since you are using `<param name="caseSensitive">false</param>`, you may even omit the `A-Z` or `a-z` in the pattern.

Note that `(?s)` enables the DOTALL mode so that a `.` could match any character including a newline.

Answer (score 3):

this appears to work:

```
[\&\-\.']
```

adding in the letters and numbers:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\&\-\.']
```

(Updated after comment)

Comment: `&-.` is range selector. Escape `-`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `\` [escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex) special characters.

```
[a-z0-9\-&\.']
```

Comment: Note that if you put the hyphen as the last character, it does not need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test of the input *contains* *anywhere* one of these characters, remove the leading `^` of the regex. That says that any of these characters has to be *the first character*.

Also, your regex does not include the character `'`.